# Golang create wkb.Polygon from a list of coordinates

Tags: go, coordinates, polygon, wkb

I have lists of coordinates in a file which I want to get their polygon. I used `wkb` library to load the coordinates, but when I try to set them into the `wkb.Polygon` object, I get an error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is [][][]float64, not [][]geom.Coord
```

This is my code:

```
var cc interface {} = collection.Features[0].Geometry.Polygon
c := cc.([][]geom.Coord)
po, err := wkb.Polygon{}.SetCoords(c)
```

I also tried:

```
c := collection.Features[0].Geometry.Polygon.([][]geom.Coord)
```

But I got:

```
Invalid type assertion: collection.Features[0].Geometry.Polygon.([][]geom.Coord) (non-interface type [][][]float64 on left)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a general Polygon like this:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/twpayne/go-geom"
)

func main() {
        unitSquare := geom.NewPolygon(geom.XY).MustSetCoords([][]geom.Coord{
                {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}},
        })
        fmt.Printf("unitSquare.Area() == %f", unitSquare.Area())
}
```

Then you can marshal it into `wkb` format.

```golang
        // marshal into wkb with litten endian
        b, err := wkb.Marshal(unitSquare, wkb.NDR)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("wkb marshal error: %s\n", err.Error())
                return
        }
        fmt.Println(b)
```